# Entity Framework - optional conditional

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm building a search engine in C# with Entity Framework and I would like to create a search function where You could pass text array to search and every element in this array would be +1 point to search score.

For example:
You have an array:

```
['test', '123', mean']
```

and
You have texts in the database:

```
['test text to show what I mean', 'other text', 'thirth text 123']
```

so the result of my function should be:

```
'test text to show what I mean' - 2 points because in this text we have: "test" word and "mean" word but we don't have the "123" word.


'thirth text 123' - 1 point because we have only '123' word here
```

We ignore texts with 0 points.

this is easy to create in C# on the server-side, but can I do it in EF Core and do that on the DataBase side?

Comment: This is a "heavy" operation database side because there is no way to use indexes. I would start by figuring out what type of search features your database platform supports and then see if that fits what you are wanting to do. Example: Sql Server has FTS (full text search) and you might be able to use this and get good performance but maybe not exactly as you have it thought out now. If that is not an option look into a text indexing service that you might be able to use for this and find a way to hook that into your database (as in how does it integrate or have a pointer back to a record).

Comment: Once you get that figured out then come back and see if you can integrate it with EF, or in ADO.NET, or using some other API. Do not get hung up on that yet, it is better to start with a solution that is scalable and performant and then figure out how to integrate that solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to use the Cache mechanism.
It will be very fast and give me so many options with easy maintenance.

Cache plus Scheduler and should be fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).